# how to autoinput in bash scripting

Tags: bash, shell

I'm tired to put username in this input by bash script i run the script but what shall i do when i rich to this line its expecting to input username

```
Vpn.sh: 1: H8JPgidIAO7T43IP: not found
Vpn.sh: 1: TEL5Fl5bZ6y857IihRmMKEJT0knhxutW: not found
 Enter Auth Username:
```

Comment: Those "not found" errors are ominous. If there's a bug in your bash script, please provide the script for us to look at.

Comment: i try to run vpn script but by bash script and add username and password automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use expect:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn Vpn.sh  
expect  "Enter Auth Username:"   
send "ThePassword\r"
expect eof
```